# Calculating Kappa value between two SNP matrices in R

Tags: r

I have problem calculating the kappa value between two SNPMatrices in R.

I've made two SNP Matrices value in R using 2 ped files of 27 individual's over 810,000 SNP data

(each ped file contains 27 rows which represent each individuals and over 810,000 columns which represent SNP datas(the alleles) and 27 individuals in each ped file are the same individuals data with only different period of time.)

I used `irr` package to calculate the kappa value between two SNP matrices.

```
irr::kappa2(cbind(matrix(q), matrix(w)))
```

In the above code, `q` and `w` are the two SNP Matrices. But an error occurs.

> Error in order(y) : unimplemented type 'raw' in 'orderVector1'

How can I fix this problem? 
Or is there another way to calculate the kappa value between the two SNPMatrices?

Comment: Hi @elite420, I don't think that you may compute `kappa2` on a dataframe that is not an n*2 matrix or dataframe, get a glance [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/irr/versions/0.84.1/topics/kappa2)

Comment: Thanks! I see the problem. Then is there a way to calculate the kappa value between n x m matrices like the SNPmatrices above?

Comment: The issue is that the statistics called `kappa`, rawly speaking, is an inter-rater statistics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) used to assess the realiability of two ratings. I am wondering what you are looking for comparing your matrices. What is you research question?
Maybe you may find answers to your question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)